# $|G|=p^3$. Prove that $\phi(x)=x^p$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and $G$ a group of order $p^3$. Prove that the $p$-th power map $x  \mapsto x^p$ is a homomorphism $G \rightarrow G$.

The abelian case is easy. Suppose $G$ is non-abelian group. If $x \in G$  or $y \in G$ has order $p$, then $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$. Thus, we can assume that $x,y$ are order of $p^2$.

That's what I did. I don't have any tools. I need your help.

Comment: How does the proof go if $x$ or $y$ has order $p$?

Comment: the center $Z=Z(G)$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup (we assume it is $\neq G$).
so let $x,y \notin Z$ and let
$$
1 \neq c := xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \Rightarrow xy=cyx
$$
Show that $c\in Z$ and multiply by $x$ and iterate to get formulas for $x^ny$ and $x^ny^n$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1132336/688539

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** If $G$ is not abelian, $|Z(G)|=p$. Then, notice that $xy=yxh$ for some $h \in Z(G)$. Therefore, you can write $(xy)^p=x^py^p h^q$ for some integer $q$; it turns out that $q$ is divisible by $p$, hence $h^q=1$.